# C# Unit Test NSubstitute Unable to Set Value in ObjectCache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute, objectcache

I am unable to insert a cache entry in ObjectCache with **Set** in my unit tests.

```
var objectCache = Substitute.For<ObjectCache>();
objectCache.Set("TestKey", object, Arg.Any<DateTimeOffset>());
```

When I step into my code

```
var cachedData = _objectCache.Get("TestKey");
// cachedData is null
```

I am using Nsubstitute for mocking libraries.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: You mock the Set on a mocked object. nothing is actually being saved in the mock. You need to mock the Get for that key in order to get the desired behavior

Comment: Not specifically related to the question, but using argument matchers as arguments to calls without `.Returns`/`.Received`/`.When`, such as `Set("TestKey", object, Arg.Any<DateTimeOffset>())` used in this question, can cause problems with tests. See the [docs](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how_not_to_use_argument_matchers) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to configure the mock for the `Get` method. See the example for the `return` method in the [NSubstitute docs](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value/).

Something like...

```
var objectCache = Substitute.For<ObjectCache>();
objectCache.Get("TestKey").Returns(...what you want it to return);
```